# If statement not executing what it should

Tags: python

```
mylist = []

for i in range(0,101,2):
    mylist.append(i)

length = len(mylist)
middle_index = length // 2
first_half = mylist[:middle_index]
second_half = mylist[middle_index:]

userRandomNumber = str(input('Please input a random number from 0-100: '))

while True:
    if userRandomNumber.isdigit():
        break
    else:
        userRandomNumber = input('Please input a number!: ')


print(first_half)
print(second_half)

if userRandomNumber in first_half:
    print('you got it')
elif userRandomNumber in second_half:
    print('you got it')
else:
    print('false!')
```

I am making a program where the user has to guess the number in the random list generated automatically. But the problem is when I run the code and input a number that is actually in the list the if statement does not work the way it should!

What is wrong with the code here? Please help!

Comment: To elaborate more, in the console when i answer the question Please input a number and type in 2 it will give me false. But two is actually in one of the lists

Comment: The list contains integers while the user input is string; you need to convert one or the other to matching type

Comment: you are comparing integer while input returns a string

Comment: It is a bad idea to check if a number is in a range because the operator `in` checks for exact presence. For example, 3.0 is not in range(10). Use conditional operators < and >: `if 0<=userRandomNumber<50`:...

Comment: @DYZ - `3.0 in range(10)` returns `True`; it's not a problem as long as you're using integers. There could be a problem with floating-point numbers, but that's a general issue with comparing floats for equality, eg. `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` is `False`

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a string. So, the number you actually enter is converted to string. Even if it didn't, the `str` would.

Your lists are full of integers. So there is a difference between an integer and string number. It is checking if the string number is in the list.

Of course, it isn't. So the `in` operator returns `False`

```
input('Please input a random number from 0-100: ')
```

Try this:

```
if int(userRandomNumber) in first_half:
    print('you got it')
elif int(userRandomNumber) in second_half:
    print('you got it')
else:
    print('false!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here this is code:

```
number=input("Type a number:")
mylist = []

for i in range(0,101,2):
    mylist.insert(1,i)

length = len(mylist)
middle_index = length // 2
first_half = mylist[:middle_index]
second_half = mylist[middle_index:]
if int(number) in first_half:
    print('you got it')
elif int(number) in second_half:
    print('you got it')
else:
    print("Nope, "+"'"+"number"+"'"+" not found in the list")
print(first_half)
print(second_half)
```

Comment: In the 3rd last line, I do not think you need to have a lot of `+`, instead, you could do - `print("Nope, '"+number+"' not found in the list")`. Also, if you had written `int(input(...))` for the first input statement, you don't need to use the `int()` function again.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, these set of code -

```
userRandomNumber = str(input('Please input a random number from 0-100: '))

while True:
    if userRandomNumber.isdigit():
        break
    else:
        userRandomNumber = input('Please input a number!: ')
```

can be changed into this -

```
while True:
    try: 
        userRandomNumber = int(input('Please input a random number from 0-100: '))
        break
            
    except:    
        pass
```

If you do not know what `try` and `except` does, then check this - [Python Exception Handling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exception-handling/)

The rest of the code can be the same, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [i for i in range(0, 101, 2)]
middle_index = len(mylist) // 2
first_half, second_half = mylist[:middle_index], mylist[middle_index:]

print(first_half, second_half, sep='\n')

userRandomNumber = ''
while not userRandomNumber.isdigit():
    userRandomNumber = input('Please input a random number from 0-100: ')
userRandomNumber = int(userRandomNumber)

# I think the point of splitting the list into two parts is probably to determine which part belongs to
# the number entered. Otherwise, if the output is 'you got it', then splitting the list makes no sense.
if userRandomNumber in first_half:
    print('you got it in the first half')
elif userRandomNumber in second_half:
    print('you got it in the second half')
else:
    print('false!')
```